# exporting entire git configuration to be used with GIT_CONFIG

Tags: git

is there any way to dump the *entire* git configuration that is currently in action (local, global, system) into a file that can then be used as `GIT_CONFIG` file?

Something like:

```sh
$ git config --list > mygit.cfg
$ GIT_CONFIG=mygit.cfg git clone /path/to/repo.git
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't really do anything (the configuration is not read from the `mygit.cfg` file but from the standard locations).

Also doing something like:

```
$ git config --file mygit.cfg --unset foo.bar
```

fails with :

> fatal: bad config line 1 in file mygit.cfg

AFAICT, the reason is that *all* git configuration files must be `INI`-style files.
However, `git config --list` dumps a plain list of `key=value` lines, which git cannot use as `GIT_CONFIG` file.

My use-case is as follows:

- I have some git problems (related to cloning a 3rd party repository) on an autobuild host (CI), that are caused by a git configuration setting

  - since it's an autobuilder changes are not persistent. so I must be able to modify the system in a script
- I really don't care (and don't want to bother) on which level that configuration exists (local, global, system,...) as the configuration is created by the autobuilder
- fixing the git problem involves *unsetting* one of the configuration values

  - unfortunately it seems that the `-c` flag to `git` only allows to *set* values, but not to unset them
- my idea is to just create an accumulated git configuration, remove the offending key from that configuration and use the amended config to do the few operations i need to do. after that, i want to revert to the original configuration

One naive approach is to just concatenate the files for the various configuration levels:

```
cat /etc/gitconfig ~/.gitconfig .git/config > mygit.cfg
```

Unfortunately this won't do, as I don't know the locations of the configuration files (yay: multi-platform builders!).
(Also: the actual location of the configuration files is an implementation detail of git; i don't want to rely on such implementation details)

So: can I dump my git configuration in a way that I can use it with git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `git config --list` outputs result in a format not suitable for using in `GIT_CONFIG`. The output must be parsed and a new config file must be recreated. This script could help you to start:

```
git config --list |
while read line; do
    git config -f cfg \
        "`echo $line | sed 's/=.\+//'`" \
        "`echo $line | sed 's/^.\+=//'`"
done
```

Two seds split `key=some value` into two separate parameters; they are quoted in case they contain spaces.

The script creates a new (or update existing) config file `cfg`.

Alternative implementation — list only keys and get values separately:

```
git config --list --name-only |
while read key; do
    git config -f cfg "$key" "`git config $key`"
done
```

Comment: omg. ugly as hell but kind of works!; it seems that your script won't properly deal with empty values. the first sed-expression (to get extract the key) should read `'s/=.*//'` instead.

Comment: See update — alternative implementation. It's still not a complete solution — it doesn't deal with multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

One could use something like

```
for SCOPE in system,global,local ; do
   EDITOR=/bin/cat git config --${SCOPE} --edit >> /path/to/my_git_config_file
done
```

to get the config values concatenated into an INI format file which can be read back in by git.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), as `git config --list` will be more robust: the config API made mixed uses of int and `size_t` types to represent length of various pieces of text it parsed, which has been updated to use the correct type (i.e.  `size_t`) throughout.

See [commit 348482d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/348482dede19296e5caa33ed73010278767c2348), [commit 6a9c235](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a9c235eb4ba32701450aff2c989792b818e02b6), [commit f011a96](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f011a9654dc2a2e3238985ba7767c1058e7cb3c2), [commit 6c7e696](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c7e6963c1b6d9a5344345d55dd537e4ab45158f), [commit f5914f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5914f4b6bcdb517733c761fe5ba9d94471eb01d), [commit 021ba32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/021ba32a7bca954235e31338c4f27b221a1807de) (10 Apr 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 342bc9e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/342bc9e29fa462b127d9e1c02aa58349e58e56f0), 28 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a9c235eb4ba32701450aff2c989792b818e02b6): use `size_t` to store parsed variable baselen
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> Most of the config parsing infrastructure is limited in what it can parse only by the size of memory, because it parses character by character, building up strbufs for keys, values, etc.
>   One exception is the "baselen" value we keep in `git_parse_source()`, which is an int.
>
> That stores the length of the `section.subsection` base, to which we can then append individual key names (by truncating back to the baselen with `strbuf_setlen()`, and then appending characters for the key name).
>
> But because it's an int, if we see an absurdly long section or subsection, we may overflow the integer, wrapping negative.
>   That negative value is then implicitly cast to a `size_t` when we pass it to `strbuf_setlen()`, creating a very large value and triggering a BUG. For example:
>
> ```
> $ {
>      printf '[foo "'
>      perl -e 'print "a" x 2**31'
>      echo '"]bar = value'
>   } >huge
> $ git config --file=huge --list
> fatal: BUG: strbuf_setlen() beyond buffer
> ```
>
> While this is obviously a silly case that we don't care about supporting, it's worth fixing it by switching to a `size_t` for a few reasons:
>
> - we should try to avoid hitting BUG assertions at all
> - avoiding integer truncation or overflow sets a good example and makes it easier to audit the code for more important issues
> - the BUG outcome is what happens in *this* instance, because we wrap negative.
>     If we used a 2**32 subsection, we'd wrap to a small positive value and actually generate wrong output (the subsection of our key would be truncated).

And:

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/348482dede19296e5caa33ed73010278767c2348): reject parsing of files over `INT_MAX`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> While the last few commits have made it possible for the config parser to handle config files up to the limits of `size_t,` the rest of the code isn't really ready for this. In particular, we often feed the keys as strings into printf "%s" format specifiers. And because the printf family of functions must return an int to specify the result, they complain. Here are two concrete examples (using glibc; we're in uncharted territory here so results may vary):
>
> Generate a gigantic .gitmodules file like this:
>
> ```
> git submodule add /some/other/repo foo
> {
>         printf '[submodule "'
>         perl -e 'print "a" x 2**31'
>  echo '"]path = foo'
> } >.gitmodules
> git commit -m 'huge gitmodule'
> ```
>
> then try this:
>
> ```
> $ git show
> BUG: strbuf.c:397: your vsnprintf is broken (returned -1)
> ```
>
> The problem is that we end up calling:
>
> ```
> strbuf_addf(&sb, "submodule.%s.ignore", submodule_name);
> ```
>
> which relies on vsnprintf(), and that function has no way to report back a size larger than `INT_MAX`.
>
> Taking that same file, try this:
>
> ```
> git config --file=.gitmodules --list --name-only
> ```
>
> On my system it produces an output with exactly 4GB of spaces. I confirmed in a debugger that we reach the config callback with the key intact: it's [2147483663](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2147483663) bytes and full of a's. But when we print it with this call:
>
> ```
> printf("%s%c", key_, term);
> ```
>
> we just get the spaces.
>
> So given the fact that these are insane cases which we have no need to support, the weird behavior from feeding the results to printf even if the code is careful, and the possibility of uncareful code introducing its own integer truncation issues, let's just declare `INT_MAX` as a limit for parsing config files.
>
> We'll enforce the limit in `get_next_char()`, which generalizes over all sources (blobs, files, etc) and covers any element we're parsing (whether section, key, value, etc). For simplicity, the limit is over the length of the `_whole`_ file, so you couldn't have two 1GB values in the same file. This should be perfectly fine, as the expected size for config files is generally kilobytes at most.
>
> With this patch both cases above will yield:
>
> ```
> fatal: bad config line 1 in file .gitmodules
> ```
>
> That's not an amazing error message, but the parser isn't set up to provide specific messages (it just breaks out of the parsing loop and gives that generic error even if see a syntactic issue). And we really wouldn't expect to see this case outside of somebody maliciously probing the limits of the config system.