# How Do I Use `GIT_CONFIG` Environment Variable

Tags: git, testing, config

I've read the `git-config` docs and checked SO questsions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249773/exporting-entire-git-configuration-to-be-used-with-git-config) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382534/can-i-use-git-config-environment-variable-to-use-a-config-file-for-all-git-comma), but I cannot seem to find an answer.

I am writing a custom tool for Git and I would like to test it. I would like to backup my global and system Git config files and then write to new config files in my tests so I don't override what I already have in place (FYI, I am testing against multiple different portable (locally built) versions of Git both for Linux and Windows in a subdirectory of my project).

My initial thought would have simply been to use `cp`:

```
# Backup the system config file
# NOTE: How do I test this automatically? (I have to enter root password)...
sudo cp ${PREFIX}/etc/gitconfig ${PREFIX}/etc/gitconfig.bak

# Backup the global config file
cp ~/.gitconfig ~/.gitconfig.bak

# DO MY TESTS HERE

# Restore system config file and delete backup
sudo cp ${PREFIX}/etc/gitconfig.bak ${PREFIX}/etc/gitconfig
sudo rm ${PREFIX}/etc/gitconfig.bak

# Restore global config file and delete backup
cp ~/.gitconfig.bak ~/.gitconfig
rm ~/.gitconfig.bak
```

However, I don't see this being done in `t/t1300-config.sh` (as of the time of this writing, the current version of the master repo is v2.32). The closest thing being done that I see is this (lines 2147-2158):

```
test_expect_success 'write to overridden global and system config' '
    cat >expect <<EOF &&
[config]
    key = value
EOF
    GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL=write-to-global git config --global config.key value &&
    test_cmp expect write-to-global &&
    GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM=write-to-system git config --system config.key value &&
    test_cmp expect write-to-system
'
```

I don't understand what is going on here. The Git Docs explain `GIT_CONFIG` is an environment variable that can be set to override the `git config` file, but if I enter the above commands in my terminal, no file `write-to-global` or `write-to-system` is created (and these are not functions in the test script either).

Can someone explain how to properly use the `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable and what's the right way to do this in a test script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment `GIT_CONFIG` variable is ancient, predating Git 1.5.3, where `git config --file` was added.  It still exists as a way to trick *other* Git commands into acting as if they were given a `--file` argument to pass *to* `git config`.  It probably should be removed, but, well, Git maintains a lot of backward compatibility!  It reminds me of the old joke about Intel putting the "backwards" in "backwards compatible"...

Until Git 1.8.2, `git clone` relied on setting `GIT_CONFIG` internally, then unsetting it.  It looks (from the linked questions and their answers) like there may still be some leftovers here.

(I found the above two items in the release notes.  All added snark is my own though.)

Git version 2.31.0 added new `GIT_CONFIG_COUNT` and `GIT_CONFIG_KEY_$i`, `GIT_CONFIG_VALUE_$i` environment variables.  They seem to be intended to add some degree of security, to avoid passing `-c` arguments that can be read from `ps` reading the command line.  But since `ps` can (at least on many systems) also read environment variables, I think this "security" is mostly illusory.

> Can someone explain how to properly use the GIT_CONFIG environment variable and what's the right way to do this in a test script?

Unless you need to put configurations somewhere other than `.git/config`, the short answer is "don't use this at all".  If you want to make sure that the *system* configuration file does not affect you, set `GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM` (to any value although I'd use `true` just for consistency).  You can then set `$HOME` and `$XCD_CONFIG_HOME` to make other Git commands look for the global Git configuration file in a predictable location, and of course the local and per-work-tree configuration files' locations are predictable already.

This method is a bit clumsy.

> ... in `t/t1300-config.sh`

This very recently (not in any release version, but in both 2.32.0 release *candidates*) gained the new `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM` and `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL` variables.  They're intended to fix some of the clumsiness of the above.  Unless you're building the various release candidates or other cutting-edge branches, you won't have this at all.  But this does seem to me a better way to deal with all of this.

Comment: Great answer! Very thorough. And I love the snark! (playful banter is fun, haha). I will try setting `$GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM`, `$HOME`, and `$XCD_CONFIG_HOME`, resp. I have to put the configurations in a tmp folder while testing so if another user runs my tests it won't override their setup.

Answer (score 2):

> The Git Docs explain `GIT_CONFIG` is an environment variable that can be set to override the git config file,

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), documentation around `GIT_CONFIG` has been updated, and clarifies the current situation.

See [commit 7342838](https://github.com/git/git/commit/734283855f86bab97a060278538d5c68ca5edbc7), [commit b3b1862](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b186262fd982d795be79a268c90efdd8116c1b), [commit 4bb9eb5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bb9eb5f91102f1df4f5d47cf7d78ed67307f144) (14 Jul 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5a9b455](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a9b455146a9b8ee16cc6aef0b33864ea502e7a9), 02 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc/git-config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3b186262fd982d795be79a268c90efdd8116c1b): clarify `GIT_CONFIG` environment variable
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The scope and utility of the `GIT_CONFIG` variable was drastically reduced by [dc87183](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc87183189b54441e315d35d48983d80ab085299) (Only use GIT_CONFIG in , 2008-06-30, Git v1.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e97f464df082d8f45e163bbf24341dceeafe89d)) (Only use `GIT_CONFIG` in "[`git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3b186262fd982d795be79a268c90efdd8116c1b/Documentation/git-config.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup>, not other programs, 2008-06-30).
> But the documentation in git-config(1) predates that, which makes it rather misleading.
>
> **These days it is really just another way to say "`--file`"**.
>
> So let's say that, and explicitly make it clear that it does not impact other Git commands (like `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM,` etc, would).
>
> I also bumped it to the bottom of the list of variables, and warned people off of using it.
> We don't have any plans for deprecation at this point, but there's little point in encouraging people to use it by putting it at the top of the list.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3b186262fd982d795be79a268c90efdd8116c1b/Documentation/git-config.txt#L371-L376):

> ### `GIT_CONFIG`
>
> If no `--file` option is provided to `git config`, use the file
> given by `GIT_CONFIG` as if it were provided via `--file`.
>
> This variable has no effect on other Git commands, and is mostly for
> historical compatibility; there is generally no reason to use it
> instead of the `--file` option.

And:

> ### [`doc/git-config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bb9eb5f91102f1df4f5d47cf7d78ed67307f144): explain --file instead of referring to `GIT_CONFIG`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The explanation for the `--file` option only refers to `GIT_CONFIG`.
> This redirection to an environment variable is confusing, but doubly so because the description of `GIT_CONFIG` is out of date.
>
> Let's [`describe`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4bb9eb5f91102f1df4f5d47cf7d78ed67307f144/Documentation/git-describe.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe))</sup> `--file` from scratch, detailing both the reading and writing behavior as we do for other similar options like `--system`, etc.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4bb9eb5f91102f1df4f5d47cf7d78ed67307f144/Documentation/git-config.txt#L146-L152):

> For writing options: write to the specified file rather than the
> repository `.git/config`.
>
> For reading options: read only from the specified file rather than from all
> available files.

---

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) adds more to "[`git var`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup>, for toolsmiths to learn various locations Git is configured with either via the configuration or hardcoded defaults.

See [commit ed773a1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8), [commit 576a37f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/576a37fccbf2a46d98a6dd367dbb3d1636e62f57), [commit 15780bb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15780bb4f0cb07624ca6bac3c430ef07e9501663), [commit cdd489e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdd489eaf9cd3c46c30b485601e2bcb989586274), [commit f74c90d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f74c90dcf7ed8ef7994ab583de089dba2a2b1a22), [commit 1e65721](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1e6572122702cbf0e3b6d3226f73e6b8b45e6e37), [commit d6546af](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6546af75c3cda2815f2e4d5322dd7a41cc0963b) (27 Jun 2023) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
See [commit 4db16f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4db16f58c7720257eea9ffb7d4e76809f2c403f0) (27 Jun 2023) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 89d62d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/89d62d5e8ef42be3a73493e8ffbede589c7a31d1), 04 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8): add config file locations
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>

> Much like with attributes files, sometimes programs would like to know the location of configuration files at the global or system levels.
> However, it isn't always clear where these may live, especially for the system file, which may have been hard-coded at compile time or computed dynamically based on the runtime prefix.
>
> Since other parties cannot intuitively know how Git was compiled and where it looks for these files, help them by providing variables that can be queried.
> Because we have multiple paths for global config values, print them in order from highest to lowest priority, and be sure to split on newlines so that "[`git var -l`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8/Documentation/git-var.txt#L21)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var#Documentation/git-var.txt--l))</sup> produces two entries for the global value.
>
> However, be careful not to split all values on newlines, since our editor values could well contain such characters, and we don't want to split them in such a case.
>
> Note in the documentation that some values may contain multiple paths and that callers should be prepared for that fact.
> This helps people write code that will continue to work in the event we allow multiple items elsewhere in the future.

`git var` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ed773a18c6e92ae4f4e016f4529d6bdfbbbd56d8/Documentation/git-var.txt#L83-L96):

> ### `GIT_CONFIG_SYSTEM`
>
> The path to the system configuration file, if one is enabled.
>
> ### `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`
>
> The path to the global (per-user) configuration files, if any.
>
> Most path values contain only one value. However, some can contain multiple
> values, which are separated by newlines, and are listed in order from highest to
> lowest priority.  Callers should be prepared for any such path value to contain
> multiple items.
>
> Note that paths are printed even if they do not exist, but not if they are
> disabled by other environment variables.